# How to get height of div before it gets closed?

Tags: jquery

I want to get the height of a clicked div before it gets closed. I have two div and when i click on the first and then on the other one and then close the first I always get the height of the second and not of that div that i close. Any suggestion on how can i get the height of the div that i close ?

```
$('.price-list').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
        height = $(this).find('.price_list').outerHeight();
});
```

and this

```
$('.price-list').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
  alert(height);
});
```

Comment: because you only have one height var which is set to the last one clicked.  In your case this is the second one. If dont want your code to do this create an var for each of your divs or get the height before it is closed.

Comment: i am not sure about this `$('.price-list').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {    var height = $(this).find('.price_list').outerHeight();
  alert(height);
});`

Answer (score 0):

you are using some theme. try this. this will show a simple way to get [height](http://api.jquery.com/height/) , [inner height](http://api.jquery.com/innerheight/) and [outer height](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/) of any element without clicking.(when user enter the mouse into element.)

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style type="text/css">

div#one, div#two{
 border: 1px solid black;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 margin:20px;
 font-size: 30px;
}

div#one{
 background-color: orange;
 width: 200px;
 height: 399px;

}

div#two{
 background-color: purple;
 width: 400px;
 height: 230px;
}

</style>


<body>

<div id="one">first div</div>
<div id="two">second div</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("div#one").mouseenter(function(){
 var _height = $(this).height();
 var _innterheight = $(this).innerHeight();
 var _outerheight = $(this).outerHeight();

    var display = "height :"+_height +"---->"+"InnerHeight :"+_innterheight +"----->"+"outerheight :"+_outerheight
    alert(display);

});


$("div#two").mouseenter(function(){
 var _height = $(this).height();
 var _innterheight = $(this).innerHeight();
 var _outerheight = $(this).outerHeight();

    var display = "height :"+_height +"---->"+"InnerHeight :"+_innterheight +"----->"+"outerheight :"+_outerheight
    alert(display);

});


</script>

</body>

</html>
```